# How to solve the circular dependency

Tags: angular

I have 3 services:

> auth.service.ts, account.service.ts, http.service.ts

While user signup I should create new account therefore I imported account.service.ts to auth.service.ts. I should do it because I use signup form data for creating a new account.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(public accountService: AccountService) {}

  signUp(name: string, phone: string, email: string, password: string): void {

    ...

  userPool.signUp(phone, password, attributeList, null, (err: any, result: any) => {
  if (err) {

    ...

    return;
  }

  this.accountService.createAccount(name, phone, email).subscribe(res => {

    ...

    this.router.navigate(['/auth/confirmation-code']);
  });
});
```

}

So as I use AWS Cognito I should add an authorization token from auth.service.ts to http.service.ts
    therefore I imported auth.service.ts to http.service.ts.

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
  private actionUrl: string;
  private headers: Headers;
  private options: RequestOptions;

  constructor(
    public _http: Http,
    public authService: AuthService 
  ) {
    this.actionUrl = 'https://example.com/dev';
    this.headers = new Headers();

    this.authService.getAuthenticatedUser().getSession((err: any, session: any) => {
      if(err) return;
      this.headers.append('Authorization', session.getIdToken().getJwtToken());
    });

    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-XSRF-TOKEN');
    this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
  }

    get(request: string): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.get(`${this.actionUrl}${request}`)
            .map(res => this.extractData(res))
            .catch(this.handleError);
   }
```

In my account.service.ts I should use http.service.ts for creating new account.

```
@Injectable()
export class AccountService {
  constructor(public httpService: HttpService) {}
```

> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   src/app/core/services/account.service.ts -> src/app/core/services/http.service.ts -> src/app/core/services/auth.service.ts -> src/app/core/services/account.service.ts
>
> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   src/app/core/services/auth.service.ts -> src/app/core/services/account.service.ts -> src/app/core/services/http.service.ts -> src/app/core/services/auth.service.ts
>
> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   src/app/core/services/http.service.ts -> src/app/core/services/auth.service.ts -> src/app/core/services/account.service.ts -> src/app/core/services/http.service.ts

I understand that this is circular dependency Error.
How to solve it? Best practice? 
All services fulfill their role and are important.

Comment: can you show  constructors of each service plz!

Comment: As a quick answer: Create a new service that will have commun parts and import it in others. :) Also, the token could be send as argument to http service instead of importing the whole auth service to http service

Comment: You need to restructure your application if you're running into these types of problems.  Circular dependencies aren't an angular specific issue, they're an application design issue, these patch solutions will not serve you in the long term.  The HTTP service needs the auth service to set auth headers, and the account service needs the http service to make http calls.  However, why would the auth service need the account service? it seems to me that the account service should be the one consuming the auth service, not the other way around.

Comment: > However, why would the auth service need the account service?
Because I am using data from signup form to creat new account.

Comment: Please look at my updated question

Comment: Thanks, i'm writing the answer

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use `Injector` for this. Inject it via constructor as usual, and then when you will need some service that leads to the circular dependency, get that service from it.

```
class HttpService {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

  doSomething() {
    const auth = this.injector.get(AuthService);
    // use auth as usual
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this code won't work because Http has other dependencies (ConnectionBackend etc...). it's better to use `this.injector.get(AccountService);` or '`this.injector.get(AuthService );`' because we can know their dependencies.

Comment: Well, this code will work, i am using it in my AuthInterceptor. But this is just a prove of concept, you can inject any service like this when needed.

Comment: Oh I see I was confused. you're right and your approach is the way to go. upvote

Comment: It's true that it is better not to fall in this problem, but sometimes there is no way to go over (by refactoring the dependency graph). For example when you want to make http call from your HttpInterceptor.

Comment: @MartinAdámek, from my experience it is not true. There's always a way to not fall into this problem, though sometimes it is very hard to see it. What I do usually is introduce one more layer of abstraction and/or move responsibilities between components, sometimes by introducing couple more components. However, this method is not a silver bullet and must be used very carefully, otherwise amount of abstraction layers will lead to a great mess, but in such a case it is well justified.

Comment: I guess you are using `Injector` in your service constructor, right? You can not do that, that's basically the same as injecting the problematic dependency directly. You have to use it later when calling a method from the service.

Comment: Anyway, if the problem is with authentication, its better to use HttpInterceptor for this, that can add necessary headers to every request on the fly.

Comment: I see your updated question. This is definitelly use case for HttpInterceptor, you should ger rid of the HttpService at all.

Comment: `HttpService` still has a reference to `AuthService` (it is used as Type in the `injector.get` method. How does this solve the circular depencency then? The files, services, classes are still referencing each other.

Answer (score 8):

@deprecated from v4.0.0 use Type or InjectionToken

```
const auth = this.injector.get(AuthService);
```

Works on Angular 10:

```
const AuthService = this.injector.get<AuthService>(AuthService);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to share a scenario that happened with me (maybe it could help someone). So I was getting the same circular dependency error and a Null Injector error too. The only thing that made my head spin was that I just had a single service and there was no literal circular dependency.

So I just tried to look the Null Injector error, the issue was that in my `app.module` I hadn't imported `HttpClientModule`. Once I imported that in imports array both error got fixed.