# Angular service to service communication and 'circular dependency detected' warnings

Tags: angular, typescript, circular-dependency

Very simply I have an AuthenticationService and a UserService. UserService is included in AuthenticationService. Then when I use AuthenticationService in UserService like:

```
constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService){}
```

I get:

```
Circular dependency detected:
src/app/core/authentication/authentication.service.ts -> src/app/shared/services/user.service.ts -> src/app/core/authentication/authentication.service.ts
```

Both services are declared in the app module providers array. Why am I getting a circular dependency?

Comment: Because as you said, you have injected `AuthenticationService` in  `UserService` and `UserService` in `AuthenticationService`

Comment: Angular doesn't know which one to create first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You injected **AuthenticationService** in **UserService** and **UserService** in **AuthenticationService**! Do not do this!

The **circular dependencies** surfaced here relate to files that either directly or indirectly are mutually importing each other. It's not an uncommon occurrence in software, but the results can vary. It doesn't necessarily mean that something wrong will happen, but it's important to surface because something wrong may happen depending on the use case.

For the most part, it's fairly easy to refactor your way towards no circular dependencies, so that's why it's a warning, but ultimately, I would consider it a good practice to move away from these types of patterns.

for Hide warning, you should add **showCircularDependencies** as following to your .**angular-cli.json**:

```
 "defaults": {
    "build": {
      "showCircularDependencies": false
    }
  }
```

Comment: Isn't this an error rather than just a warning, Angular won't be able to create these two services if it is deadlocked.

Comment: Why not use the "clasic solution" ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46832072/how-to-solve-the-circular-dependency