# Resolving circular dependency in Angular by exporting it from a single file

Tags: angular, typescript, circular-dependency

I have a project which has big scope of circular dependency. To tackle the issue I have created the **simple project with circular dependency** on purpose to come up with the solution.

I have come accross different solutions like using injections.
[How to solve the circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46832072/how-to-solve-the-circular-dependency)

but there is also a solution **to export all dependencies from a single file** which is given by this article https://medium.com/visual-development/how-to-fix-nasty-circular-dependency-issues-once-and-for-all-in-javascript-typescript-a04c987cf0de

I followed the instructions as followed:

moduleA.ts

```
import { MODULE_B_NAME } from "./internal";

export const MODULE_A_NAME = 'Module A';

export class ModuleA {

  public static getName(): string {

    return MODULE_B_NAME;

  }

}
```

modeulB.ts

```
import { MODULE_A_NAME } from "./internal";

export const MODULE_B_NAME = 'Module B';

export class ModuleB {

  public getName(): string {

    return MODULE_A_NAME;

  }

}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModuleA } from './internal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'test01';


  getSomething() {

    return ModuleA.getName();
  }



}
```

internal.ts

```
export * from './app.component';
export * from './moduleA';
export * from './moduleB';
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './internal';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

I followed the steps, still it is given circular dependency warnings.
what is it that Im not doing right?
[image]

Comment: You are returning MODULE_B_NAME from class A, are you importing that too from internal.ts?

Comment: @GouravGarg yes..all imports are from ./internal