# WARNING in Circular dependency detected - Angular 9

Tags: angular

I got this warning and I can't solve it.

The problem is with ComponentFactoryResolver on modal that i create.

The full warning:

```
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
projects/admin-panel/src/app/form/components/form-fields-modal/form-fields-modal.component.ts -> projects/admin-panel/src/app/form/components/annotation/annotation.component.ts -> projects/admin-panel/src/app/form/components/form-fields-modal/form-fields-modal.component.ts
```

My Components:

Annotation.component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormFieldsModalComponent } from '../form-fields-modal/form-fields-modal.component';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FormFields } from '../../models/form-fields.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-annotation',
  templateUrl: './annotation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./annotation.component.scss']
})
export class AnnotationComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() field: FormFields;
  @Input() position: any;

  @Output() fieldsUpdated = new EventEmitter<FormFields>();
  isResizing = false;
  _isDragging = false;

  annotationPosition = { x: 300, y: 100 };
  private minimumSize = 20;
  private annotationWidth = 0;
  private annotationHeight = 0;
  private elementPositionX = 0;
  private elementPositionY = 0;
  private mouseX = 0;
  private mouseY = 0;
  private _resizeMouseEventMove: (event: MouseEvent) => void;
  private _resizeMouseEventUp: (event: MouseEvent) => void;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef,
              private _modalService: NgbModal) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.makeResizableDiv(this.elementRef.nativeElement.firstChild);
  }

  onDragEnded(event) {
    console.log('drag end');
    // this._isDragging = false;
    this.annotationPosition = event.source.getFreeDragPosition();
    this.field.positionX =  this.annotationPosition.x;
    this.field.positionY = this.annotationPosition.y;
    const fieldsUpdated = new FormFields();
    fieldsUpdated.positionX = this.annotationPosition.x;
    fieldsUpdated.positionY = this.annotationPosition.y;
    this.fieldsUpdated.emit(fieldsUpdated);
    console.log(`Annotation dragged: position x: ${this.annotationPosition.x} position y: ${this.annotationPosition.y}`);
    this._isDragging = false;
  }

  makeResizableDiv(element) {
    const resizers = element.querySelectorAll('.resizer');
    resizers.forEach(resizer => {
      resizer.addEventListener('mousedown', (event: MouseEvent) => {
        this.calculateResizerAttributes(event, element);

        this._resizeMouseEventMove = (evt: MouseEvent) => this.resize(evt, element, resizer);
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', this._resizeMouseEventMove);

        this._resizeMouseEventUp = (evt: MouseEvent) => this.stopResizing(element);
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', this._resizeMouseEventUp);
        // window.addEventListener('mouseup', (ev: MouseEvent) => this.stopResizing(element));
      });
    });
  }

  calculateResizerAttributes(event: MouseEvent, element) {
    this.annotationWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('width').replace('px', ''));
    this.annotationHeight = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('height').replace('px', ''));
    this.elementPositionX = element.offsetLeft;
    this.elementPositionY = element.offsetTop;
    this.mouseX = event.pageX;
    this.mouseY = event.pageY;
    this.isResizing = true;
  }

  resize(event: MouseEvent, element?, resizer?) {
    if (!this.isResizing) {
      return;
    }

    if (resizer.classList.contains('bottom-right')) {
      console.log('bottom-right');
      const width = this.annotationWidth + (event.pageX - this.mouseX);
      const height = this.annotationHeight + (event.pageY - this.mouseY);
      if (width > this.minimumSize) {
        element.style.width = width + 'px';
        element.style.right = this.elementPositionX + (event.pageX - this.mouseX) + 'px';
        this.field.width = width;
      }
      if (height > this.minimumSize) {
        element.style.height = height + 'px';
        this.field.height = height;
      }
    } else if (resizer.classList.contains('bottom-left')) {
      const height = this.annotationHeight + (event.pageY - this.mouseY);
      const width = this.annotationWidth - (event.pageX - this.mouseX);
      if (width > this.minimumSize) {
        element.style.width = width + 'px';
        element.style.left = this.elementPositionX + (event.pageX - this.mouseX) + 'px';
        this.field.width = width;
        // Get TranslateX value for compute the position x after resizing
        const elementStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element);
        // tslint:disable-next-line: deprecation
        const translateX = new WebKitCSSMatrix(elementStyle.webkitTransform);
        this.field.positionX = translateX.m41 + parseInt(element.style.left, 10);
      }
      if (height > this.minimumSize) {
        element.style.height = height + 'px';
        this.field.height = height;
      }
    } else if (resizer.classList.contains('top-right')) {
      const width = this.annotationWidth + (event.pageX - this.mouseX);
      const height = this.annotationHeight - (event.pageY - this.mouseY);
      if (width > this.minimumSize) {
        element.style.width = width + 'px';
        this.field.width = width;
      }
      if (height > this.minimumSize) {
        element.style.height = height + 'px';
        element.style.top = this.elementPositionY + (event.pageY - this.mouseY) + 'px';
        this.field.height = height;
        const elementStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element);
        // tslint:disable-next-line: deprecation
        const translateY = new WebKitCSSMatrix(elementStyle.webkitTransform);
        this.field.positionY = translateY.m42 + parseInt(element.style.top, 10);

      }
    } else {
      const width = this.annotationWidth - (event.pageX - this.mouseX);
      const height = this.annotationHeight - (event.pageY - this.mouseY);
      if (width > this.minimumSize) {
        element.style.width = width + 'px';
        element.style.left = this.elementPositionX + (event.pageX - this.mouseX) + 'px';
        this.field.width = width;
         // Get TranslateX value for compute the position x after resizing
        const elementStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element);
         // tslint:disable-next-line: deprecation
        const translateX = new WebKitCSSMatrix(elementStyle.webkitTransform);
        this.field.positionX = translateX.m41 + parseInt(element.style.left, 10);
      }
      if (height > this.minimumSize) {
        element.style.height = height + 'px';
        element.style.top = this.elementPositionY + (event.pageY - this.mouseY) + 'px';
        this.field.height = height;
        const elementStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element);
        // tslint:disable-next-line: deprecation
        const translateY = new WebKitCSSMatrix(elementStyle.webkitTransform);
        this.field.positionY = translateY.m42 + parseInt(element.style.top, 10);
      }
    }
  }

  stopResizing(event: MouseEvent) {
    this.isResizing = false;
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', this._resizeMouseEventMove);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', this._resizeMouseEventUp);
    const fieldUpdated = new FormFields();
    fieldUpdated.width = this.field.width;
    fieldUpdated.height = this.field.height;
    fieldUpdated.positionY = this.field.positionY;
    fieldUpdated.positionX = this.field.positionX;
    this.fieldsUpdated.emit(fieldUpdated);
  }

  openFormFieldsModal() {
    const modalRef = this._modalService.open(FormFieldsModalComponent, { windowClass: 'form-fields', centered: true, size: 'xl' });
    modalRef.componentInstance.field = this.field;
  }
}
```

form-fields-modal.component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, Input, ApplicationRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormFields } from '../../models/form-fields.model';
import { FormFieldsFacade } from '../../form-fields.facade';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AnnotationComponent } from '../annotation/annotation.component';

interface OptionField {
  position: number;
  name: string;
  positionX: number;
  positionY: number;
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-fields-modal',
  templateUrl: './form-fields-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-fields-modal.component.scss']
})
export class FormFieldsModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() field: FormFields;
  fieldsGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef,
              private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private _formFieldsFacade: FormFieldsFacade,
              private _activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
              private _app: ApplicationRef,
              private _factoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
              private _injector: Injector) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._setupFormBuilder();
    this.fieldsGroup.setValue({
      name: this.field.name,
      type: this.field.type,
      description: this.field.description,
      note: this.field.note,
    });
  }

  // Setup
  private _setupFormBuilder() {
    this.fieldsGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      type: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
      note: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  onSubmitFormButtonClicked() {
    const field = new FormFields();
    field.name = this.fieldsGroup.get('name').value;
    field.type = this.fieldsGroup.get('type').value;
    field.description = this.fieldsGroup.get('description').value;
    field.note = this.fieldsGroup.get('note').value;
    this._formFieldsFacade.updateFormFields(field, this.field.id);
  }

  onCancelFormButtonClicked() {
    this._activeModal.close();
  }

  addOptionField() {
    console.log('append option');
    const container = document.querySelector('.ng2-pdf-viewer-container') as HTMLElement;
    const currentPage = document.querySelector(`.page[data-page-number='${this.field.formPage}']`) as HTMLElement;
    if (container === null || currentPage === null) {
      return;
    }

    // const topBoundry = parentAnnotation.scrollTop;
    // const position = {
    //   x: 10,
    //   y: topBoundry + 10
    // };

    // Create a annotation object
    const optionField: OptionField = {
      position: 1,
      name: 'בדיקה',
      positionX: this.field.positionX ,
      positionY: this.field.positionY,
      width: 25,
      height: 25
    };


    this._appendOptionField(optionField, true);
  }


 private _appendOptionField(fields: FormFields, isNew: boolean) {
    const factory = this._factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(AnnotationComponent);
    const annotationElement = document.createElement('div');
    annotationElement.className = 'option-annotation';
    document.getElementById('annotation-' + this.field.id).appendChild(annotationElement);
    const ref = factory.create(this._injector, [], annotationElement);
    ref.instance.field = fields;
    ref.instance.position = { x: fields.positionX, y: fields.positionY };
    this._app.attachView(ref.hostView);
  }


}
```

When i remove component factory resolver the warning disappeared but i need this.

I load data to the modal from annotation component and then i need to manipulate the dom and add elements to annotation component.

Answer (score 0):

So why this is happening is

That From form Field Instance you are refering to Annotation and from Annotation back to  From From Form Field component

Form -> Annotation -> Form Field.

Do one thing create a middle service for referring them.

Form -> Service -> Annotation

Annotation -> Service -> Form

Comment: How can i referring them on the service?

Comment: the main thing is you got to have a middle layer. whether its a service or component or anything else.

Comment: inject your componentResolver in service and the methods which are referring to each other component move them in service, and other properties which they need pass them to service via component in parameters.

Comment: I create a service and now the error is the same but on the service and annotation component

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46832072/how-to-solve-the-circular-dependency